# How to multiply two editText's value and accoringly get value in a textView when user enters value in android

Tags: android, calculator, textchanged

I have two EditText and one TextView in my activity,I want to multiple both edittext value thing is that when user entering values to any of edittext ,Accordingly the textView value should be change..My code is as below:

EDITTEXTS:qty,price
TextView:tv_subtotal

**main.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.ui;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Pref;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Utils;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class PlaceOrderActivity extends ListActivity {
    Button confirm, shipping;
    RelativeLayout rl_adress;
    TextView product_name;
    TextView tv_adress;
    TextView tv_select_adres;
    EditText qty;
    EditText price;
    TextView tv_subtotal;
    TextView tv_total;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String method;
    ImageView back;
    Double total, subtotal, min_qty, min_agree_prc, max_agree_prc, min_agree_qty, Max_agree_qty, min_qty_unit_name, max_price, min_price;
    Intent i = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        System.out.println("::::::::::::my  custome Id inside ::::::::::place order" + Pref.getValue(PlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, ""));
        // FINDINLG IDS...!!
        qty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_qty);
        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_price);
        rl_adress = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_adress);
        product_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
        tv_adress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_adress);
        tv_select_adres = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_select_adress);
        tv_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        tv_subtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_subtotal);
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_back);
        qty.setCursorVisible(false);
        price.setCursorVisible(false);

        lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        String[] shipMethods = new String[] { "Sea Freight", "Air Cargo", "Express" };
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, shipMethods);

        shipping = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_shiping_method);
        shipping.setText("Select shipping Method");
        if (Pref.getValue(PlaceOrderActivity.this, Const.FLAG_ADDRESS, "").equals("")) {

            max_agree_prc = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_AGREE_MAX_PRICE));
            min_agree_prc = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_AGREE_MIN_PRICE));
            Max_agree_qty = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_AGREE_MAX_QTY));
            min_agree_qty = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_AGREE_MIN_QTY));
            min_qty = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY));
            min_qty_unit_name = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY_UNIT_NAME));
            max_price = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MAX_PRICE));
            min_price = Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_PRICE));
            product_name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME));
        }
        qty.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                qty.setCursorVisible(true);

            }
        });

        price.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                price.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        });

        // SELECT ADDRESS CLICK EVENT..!
        rl_adress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                i = new Intent(PlaceOrderActivity.this, AddressListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        shipping.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                setListAdapter(adapter);
                lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                method = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                shipping.setText(method);
                i.putExtra("shipping", method);
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
        confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Checking for quantity and price...!!!
                if (Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString()) >= min_qty) {
                    // check for quantity range
                    if (Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()) >= min_price && Integer.parseInt(price.getText().toString()) <= max_price) {
                        // check for price range

                    } else {
                        Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(PlaceOrderActivity.this, "Enter Price in Range", "ALERT", "OK");
                    }

                } else {
                    Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(PlaceOrderActivity.this, "Enter Quantity in Range", "ALERT", "OK");
                }

            }

        });

    }

    private void calculate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double QuantyInt = 1;
        double PriceInt = 0;

        if (qty != null)

            QuantyInt = Double.parseDouble(qty.getText().toString());

        if (price != null)
            PriceInt = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());

        subtotal = (QuantyInt * PriceInt);
        String textResult = "Your BMI is " + subtotal;
        tv_subtotal.setText(textResult);
        tv_total.setText(textResult);

    }
}
```

Comment: 2 things to be mentioned 1. smells like school work, 2. listactivity seems to be an overkill. Generally the idea should be to have 3 textviews, on the first 2 attach a textwatcher and if the first 2 textviews are filled, dispaly the text on the 3rd.

Comment: rite..i have edited my code.Please see it.